# Randomly choose elements from a matrix, must include those not chosen before

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, random

I have a time varying `16*1` vector and I want to randomly pick 11 elements from this vector at each time instant. But I want that the picked elements between consecutive times be as different as possible. For example, if elements `1:11` are chosen at time `t`, I want the elements `12:16` to definitely be among chosen elements at time instant `t+1`. The same condition should be met from `t+1` to `t+2`, and so on.

This is what I already tried:

```
N=16;
M=11;
for t=1:96
    x(:,:,t)=randn(N,1)
end

for t=1:96
    E = eye(M,N);
    Phi(:,:,t)=E(randperm(M),randperm(N));
end

for t=1:96
    y(:,:,t)=Phi(:,:,t)*x(:,:,t);
end
```

and multiplied `Phi(:,:,t)` by my `16*1` vector at time instant `t(x(t))`.

But this is completely random and does not consider variety of selection between two consecutive time instants. In fact each `x(:,:,t)` contains readings of 16 sensor nodes and I want that all of these  sensor nodes play their parts in generating measurements `y(:,:,t)` between two time instants. **I must have readings from all 16 sensor nodes in time period `t:t+1`.** I don't want that one sensor reading is missed  in `[t:t+1]`. I appreciate any help.

Comment: "most", "surely" are very unscientific. What you vaguely describe is some sort of rules to choose the next from, can you be a bit more clear about what are the constrains? Also, note that once you set constrains, then you are losing randomness. If randomness is important sometimes, just be aware that you are loosing it

Comment: About randomness, it shows itself elsewhere (I hope), and I'm not completely losing it. I just want variety. To make it more clear, there is a matrix `Phi(:,:,t)` as I defined above which is M*N and has exactly one `1` in each row and at most one `1` in each column. I use this matrix to randomly choose `11` elements from my `16*1` vector `x(t)`. At next time `(t+1)` this random matrix Phi changes and chooses `11`  randomly chosen elements from `x(t+1)`.

Comment: I think you may have the [XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Can you show us what you want to do, instead of the problems you are having while trying to solve it? Also note that if you loose randomness it doesnt "appear" elsewere. You loose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have `N=16` elements, and are choosing `M=11` each time. That means there can be at most `N-M` elements different at time `t+1` and time `t`, and you will have an overlap of `M-(N-M)`.

```
M = 11;
N = 16;
idx = 1:N;          % All numbers to choose from
r = randperm(N, M); % Choose 11 random elements from 16 to start
for t = 1:10
    previouslypicked = ismember(idx,r); % Get elements which aren't in previous choice
    rnew = idx(~previouslypicked);      % Start off with elements not previously picked
    r = [rnew, r(randperm(M, M-(N-M)))] % Append random selection of other elements
end
```

Example:

```
% Initial vector from r = randperm(N,M)
r = [2     7     8    11    14     9    15    16     1    13     5];
% After one iteration
r = [3     4     6    11    12     2     8    10    13     9    16];
```

The first vector was missing `[3,4,6,10,12]`, which are all included in the second vector. The other elements in the second vector are random and different from the ones manually chosen because they weren't previously present.

**So all elements are accounted for between any two consecutive iterations `t:t+1`.**

---

This could, of course, be done in one line. I only split things out for clarity, this example also includes generation of `Phi`:

```
M = 11; N = 16; T = 96; idx = 1:N; 
r = randperm(N, M); 
Phi = zeros(M, N, T);
for t = 1:T
    r = [idx(~ismember(idx,r)), r(randperm(M, M-(N-M)))];
    % Get Phi, which is M*N*T with 1 in each row & at most 1 in each column, for each t
    E = zeros(M,N);                 % Set up zeros matrix
    E(sub2ind([M,N], 1:M, r)) = 1;  % Set desired elements to 1, satisfying Phi format
    Phi(:,:,t) = E;                 % Assign to layer of Phi
end
```

---

Again, this can be done in one line, removing the need for `E`.

```
M = 11; N = 16; T = 96; idx = 1:N; 
r = randperm(N, M); 
Phi = zeros(M, N, T);
for t = 1:T
    r = [idx(~ismember(idx,r)), r(randperm(M, M-(N-M)))];
    Phi(sub2ind([M,N,T], 1:M, r, ones(1,M)*t)) = 1;
end
```